# how to test if the correct function is called in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to learn how to write tests using phpunit.

In the test case i am trying to write i am testing 3 methods. Test is if method 1 returns false then call method 2 and 3 else just stop.

```
class MyTest {

 $mock1->getMock('some class1')
 $mock1->expect($this->once())
       ->method('method1')
       ->will($this->returnValue(false));

 $mock2->getMock('some_class2')
 $mock2->expect($this->once())
       ->method('method2')
$mock2->method2($arg)

 $mock2->expect($this->once())
       ->method('method3')
$mock3->method3($arg)
}
```

how do i test if method 2 and 3 were called.
Currently i am getting a failure that No Test was Found

Comment: Is that you actual code ? You need to declare some test methods in your class right. Seems like PHPUnit does not find any 'testMethod()' to execute (or with annotation)

Comment: Thats not my actual code. I have written a rough code to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation, roughly this is how your class should look like:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
    //initialize objects for each method to work with
    }

    public function testFeature()
    {
         $arg = 'something';
         $mock1->getMock('some class1');
         $mock1->expect($this->once())
               ->method('method1')
               ->will($this->returnValue(false));

         $mock2->getMock('some_class2');
         $mock2->expect($this->once())
               ->method('method2');
        $mock2->method2($arg);

         $mock2->expect($this->once())
               ->method('method3');
        //$mock3->method3($arg);

    }
}
```

Comment: thats right. it should have been $mock2->method3($arg).

Comment: When testing a method/function myFunction you should have testMyFunction(or anithing beginning with test) so that phpunit knows that it is a test case, this way you won`t have : No Test was Found